# Convert UTM to decimal degrees with Esri's ArcGis with C#

Tags: c#, arcgis, esri

I need to convert a user's UTM input (WGS 1984) into Decimal Degrees, preferably using ESRI's ArcGis.  I've already got the code to retrieve the zone (formatted like 14N, 22S, etc.) and the easting and northing factors.  What do I do from here?

Edit: we expect the input as a string like: `14N 423113mE 4192417mN`.  I can easily extract the numbers (and a character) `14`, `N`, `423113`, and `4192417` from the string above.  I just need to somehow translate that to Decimal Degrees.

Comment: There are a number of JavaScript website available to do the conversion, one such website is http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html. Email the author and ask his permission to port the JavaScript code to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific information about input data.

Here is some general info to start from:

1. The easiest way is to use Geoprocessing engine to reproject the whole feature class. Use [C# class for Project tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/004700003nzm000000/) from Data Management toolbox.
2. Another way is to use [Project](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000020r000000) method of IGeometry is you want project only several features.

**EDIT:** for your input data use solution 2.

One more easier way is to use .NET port of open-source library Proj.4 - [Proj4Net](http://proj4net.codeplex.com). For such simple task it is much more easier to use than ArcObjects classes.

Comment: UTM is projection. It can be done for many datums. So, esriSRGeoCSType should point to the datum you need. In example, for WGS84 it will be [esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000002t000000). There is no such thing as `Decimal Degree projection`. Decimal Degrees represent coordinates on the surface of ellipsoid. Projection is used to transform that coordinates to plane surface (usually X, Y in meters, feets). So you don't need `esriSRProjCSType` for Decimal Degree output. Check wikipedia pages Map projection, Datum (geodesy)